# Showing an induction step for a congruence relation.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Let $a$ be an odd integer such that $a^{2^{n-2}}\equiv 1\; \mod {2^{n}}$. I want to show that $a^{2^{n-1}}\equiv 1\; \mod {2^{n+1}}$.

My try:

The integer $a^{2^{n-1}}$ is obtained from $a^{2^{n-2}}$ by the relation $a^{2^{n-1}}=a^{2^{n-2}}*a^{2^{n-2}}$. Hence
since $a^{2^{n-2}}=1+ \alpha  {2^{n}}$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb Z$
then $a^{2^{n-1}}=a^{2^{n-2}}+ \alpha  {2^{n}} a^{2^{n-2}}$
but I can't go any further. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost finished. The square of $1+\alpha2^n$ is $1+(2)\alpha 2^n +\alpha^22^{2n}$. The second term is $\alpha 2^{n+1}$ and the third is divisible by $2^{n+1}$ if $n\ge 1$, since $2n\ge n+1$.

Comment: I see that for $a$ being odd is not needed here, it was only needed for the starting point of the induction $n=3$, i.e, $a^2\equiv 1 \mod 8$.